# How compactly return object from javascript closure?

Tags: javascript, closures

Consider:

```
myPromise.then(r => { return {data:r.data, urls:r.list}});
```

This works, but that is not:

```
myPromise.then(r => {data:r.data, urls:r.list});
```

Because the javascript "thinks" that `{` is begin of code block, so I have to put return and only then return object.

Is there more compact way which stays with one line `then` anonymous function, but return object?

Comment: myPromise.then(r => {{data:r.data, urls:r.list}});

Comment: `myPromise.then(r =>0||{data:r.data, urls:r.list});` doesn't need balanced...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the parenthesis notation: `()`

```
myPromise.then(r => ({data:r.data, urls:r.list}));
```